# Android datepicker setMinDate shows older dates

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to limit the date selection by setting minDate:

```
getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 500);
```

Before selection the date picker looks like this:

[image]

Today is 30 July, however older dates are still displayed in the dialog. When I try to select an old date it disappears:

[image]

As a user I find this strange. Any ideas why this happens? Maybe a bug?

Comment: what is `-500` ..it is showing as you want..whats the problem..

Comment: @RanjitPati setMinDate expects a date in the past or it will throw an exception, so we subtract some milliseconds.

Comment: its fine..but you set the minimum date as currenttimemillis which is today(current one) date. in your picker it is showing perfectly..i.e from today and onwards..

Comment: @RanjitPati yeah but initially it displays 29 and Juni which I find very strange

Comment: i think you tested it in midnight or it took UTC midtime when you tested.

Comment: @RanjitPati my phones timezone is GMT+2 and I took the screenshots 30 minutes ago, at 10:00

Comment: There are bugs, lots of them. I've found the WTFs/minute metric when working with date pickers to be quite high. Consider debugging the platform source to find an explanation why it behaves so.